# How to find exact sub-string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring, contains

I'm trying to find the sub-string(taking from one data frame) from main-string(from main data frame), but I didn't get the desired result. The following are file details and output.

First data frame

```
handleid
49483
51466
83821
94159
105068
```

I want to search ***49483*** from the main data frame (**id** column). The result as follows.

```
id                collection_id     dc_language_iso
dli_ndli/49483    NaN               English
dli_ndli/494830   NaN               Kannada
dli_ndli/494831   NaN               Kannada
dli_ndli/494832   NaN               Kannada
```

Above results shows that I am getting 4983, 49830, 49831, 49832. But I only want first row i.e `dli_ndli/49483 NaN English`. I don't want the rows with 49830, 49831, 49832 values as substring.

I am using ***contains*** functions available in pandas.

Comment: Please provide your second dataframe @Rajesh

Comment: Is the substring you are looking for always the last sub-string in the cell, or can there be other chars after it?

Comment: @Aryerez Yes its at the last position and no characters/numbers after it.

Comment: Add `'$'` (end-of-string marker) to the end of the searched string. In other words, search for `"49483$"`.

Comment: @Vishnudev Second data frame is same as output i.e it contains id, collection_id and dc_language_iso columns.

Comment: @DYZ Do I need to add $ with hanldeid in my first data frame?

Comment: You can add it with `+` (concatenation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
 newdf[newdf['id'].str.contains('49483$', regex=True)] 

#Out[216]: 
#               id  collection_id dc_language_iso
#0  dli_ndli/49483            NaN         English
```

Comment: Will not work in two different dataframes @RajeshAhir

Answer (score 0):

assuming everything is strings...you can do this:

```
main_df[main_df['id'].str.split('/',expand=True)[1] == df1['handleid'][0]]
```

here main_df is the main dataframe, df1 is the first dataframe, and `df1['handleid'][0]` is `'49483'`...you can alter the code as necessary to perform on any/all values in df1